# Does the error indicate that I should not chain methods in embedded ruby when deploying to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

During development, my rails app works just fine.
But when I deployed it to heroku, it is producing the error indicated below.
Should I avoid chaining methods in embedded ruby to avoid this error?

```
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455724+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07]     4: 
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455724+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07]     5:     <% @articles.sort_by { |p| p["updated_at"] }.reverse.each do |article| %>
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455726+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07]     6:         <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 50vw;">
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455726+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07]     7:             <h5 class="card-header"><%= article.name %></h5>
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455726+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07]     8:             <div class="card-body">
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455727+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07]   
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455727+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07] app/views/articles/index.html.erb:5:in `sort_by'
2021-05-21T13:26:25.455728+00:00 app[web.1]: [82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07] app/views/articles/index.html.erb:5
2021-05-21T13:26:25.483970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=deardiaryapp.herokuapp.com request_id=82400545-7eab-4e17-8f42-b90549f74b07 fwd="49.144.135.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=372ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2021-05-21T13:26:25.924087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=deardiaryapp.herokuapp.com request_id=0cb3e121-25c0-4aa8-a8fd-9b8b0c884dca fwd="49.144.135.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

Comment: I don't see an actual error message there so it is hard to say what's going on. The `.sort_by { |p| p["updated_at"] }.reverse` part should probably be pushed into the database as `.order(updated_at: :desc)` though. I'm also curious about the differences between your development and production environments: same databases, same data in the database, ...

Comment: I am betting on `NoMethodErrror (undefined method \`[]' for Abc:Xyz)` where `Abc:Xyz` is most likely `nil:NilClass`

Comment: I editted the syntax to <% @articles.order(updated_at: :desc).each do |article| %> but it is still throwing error on this line. I used Postgresql in development and pushed it to production

Comment: Can You provide also the lines above of the lines which You have showed?

Comment: This is the only error in the logs

Comment: Solved it: I needed to run this command heroku run rails db:migrate